# Writing and debugging Craft plugins

Tags: plugin-development, craft3

I think my question is simple but may fall outside of the scope of this forum. What is best practices when writing and debugging Craft plugins? Obviously, one way to do so is to create a account on a server, write the code, upload and install it and then trigger the code using twig in a web page. Uggg...

Is there a good (hopefully free, open source) way to write and debug plug in code for Craft, perhaps locally?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what this has to do with Craft because it's the same process with every single PHP file... You download xampp/wampp/lampp or whatever you want, install it, open it, activate your apache and MySQL, copy your project into your `htdocs` folder, create your database at `localhost/phpmyadmin` and start to create your plugin.

Anyway when you use a good IDE it makes absolutely no difference whether you create it locally or not since a good IDE will upload/download/compare your files on the server automatically. You don't have to upload all your files with programs like Filezilla or something like that

Comment: I think he's looking for resources on "how to write a plugin", not simply how to code.

Comment: @LindseyD oh sorry. Seems like I misunderstood the question then.. I already showed him pluginfactory.io and the Craft docs that's why I thougth he has enough resources for that and just wanted to know how to create it not on a remote server. I'll edit my question with all known resources and a guideline in a few hours after my sleep. Maybe he'll clarify the issue until then

Comment: No. I think Robin nailed the question. I am very rusty. Helping out some friends and dusting off some old skills that I forgot I had. I appreciate your. Yes, I am asking what people do for local dev work. Like I said...it's  been a while!