# Getting unknown property: craft\web\Application::GeneralConfig

Tags: craft3

Sorry, rusty at PHP and learning Craft.

My code looks like this:

```
$url = craft::$app->GeneralConfig->siteUrl();
```

What am I doing wrong? I want to build a URL for some links in a plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use a proper IDE or take a look into the source code to get to know the functions of the class. As you can see in the [class reference](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-base-applicationtrait.html#getConfig()-detail) the function is called

```
Craft::$app->getConfig()
```

However - in order to create urls you should use the [UrlHelper](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-helpers-urlhelper.html)

Comment: you have referenced a "good IDE" in another question of mine as well. See [link]https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/25288/8071. You seem to have strong opinions about IDE's. What specifically in your estimation is a good or proper IDE? Are there ways to set up IDE's to get Craft classes autocompleted? Are there plugins that help? Can you recommend a specific IDE or environment? I am open to what a "proper IDE" is, please tell me. I am currently using Netbeans.

Comment: I would not even start to create a plugin without autocomplete, because it saves you so much time. NetBeans should be capable, but I personally don't like it at all. Here is a good article about the topic https://nystudio107.com/blog/so-you-wanna-make-a-craft-3-plugin#phpstorm Phpstorm completes your code automatically, warns you about deprecated functions, enables twig autosuggestion, explains all functions, properties and magic methods a class has and so on. So when you type `Craft::` you'll see every possibility you have. No plugin needed, no  real setup needed

Comment: Wow...oh wow! Using PHPStorm is massively helpful. I just learned how to set up a vagrant box with PHPStorm with xdebug. Wow...mind blown. Was used to this kind of capability using Visual Studio for VB.net. I always hated how primitive using echos, print_r and their ilk in doing web development. Mind blown. Thanks for pushing me @Robin. I appreciate your help.